# Problem with priority talking in vivox unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, chat, voice

Hello i have a problem with vivox in unity. Everything is working but when im talking and my friends talking we cant hear each other but when i stop talking i can hear them. Is there any option to fix this?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO! Can you please provide more details for the community to help out appropriately such as mentioning the code that you wrote? Thanks.

Comment: the code isn't necessary because i didn't wrote anything about priority and im using not positional voice chat type